# How to write rasters after stacking them?

Tags: r, raster

There are several raster files that I want to manipulate and then write them again.

```
rasterfiles   <- list.files("C:\\data", "*.envi", full.names = TRUE)
d1 <-  overlay(stack(rasterfiles ), 
               fun=function(x) movingFun(x, fun=mean, n=3, na.rm=TRUE))
d2=unstack(d1)
```

I am grateful to any idea on how we write `d2` (rasters)

Comment: You could try one of the formats mentioned in `?writeFormats`.

Comment: I guess it was just meant as a dummy example but you cannot call of variable with a name starting with an integer, it will throw an error `Unexpected symbol in "10rasterfiles"`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 writeRaster(d1, file="d1.nc") #other file formats such as .envi work as well
```

works since `d1` is one single raster and not a list of rasters: indeed the result of `overlay` is one single raster (see `?overlay`).
Additionally the concept of `stack` is precisely to take several rasters having one layer and produce one raster with several layer.
Eventually if you really want to save each layer separately, you can `unstack` your raster prior to writing.
In which case:

```
d2 <- unstack(d1)
outputnames <- paste(seq_along(d2), ".nc",sep="")
for(i in seq_along(d2)){writeRaster(d2[[i]], file=outputnames[i])}
```

Comment: the result of `overlay`is one single raster: see `?overlay`. Plus you stacked your rasters, meaning from several raster having on single layer you made one single raster having several layers.

Comment: plannapus - you should incorporate your comment into the answer.  That's the important point, I think :-)

Comment: `unstack(d1)` gives you a list of RasterLayers which you can individually write in a file using `writeRaster` (with the latest version of package raster, [2.0-41](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/)).

Comment: it means exactly what it says: that a file with this name already exists in the current directory. So either you save it with a different name, in a different directory or you overwrite it using argument `overwrite=TRUE` (as in `for(i in seq_along(d2)){writeRaster(d2[[i]], file=outputnames[i], overwrite=TRUE)}`).

Comment: You just have to add your path to `outputnames`. Like `outputnames <- paste("C:\\whateverpathyouwant\\", seq_along(d2), ".nc",sep="")`. This is just meant to be an example: i don't know where stuff are stored on your computer and where you want to store things or call your files. You just have to input somehow to `writeRaster` at some point the name of the files (with pathes) you want to write.

Answer (score 8):

Plannapus solution should work. Alternatively, you can either write to a single file in one step:

```
 rasterfiles   <- list.files("C:\\data", "*.envi", full.names = TRUE)
 d1 <-  overlay(stack(rasterfiles ), 
           fun=function(x) movingFun(x, fun=mean, n=3, na.rm=TRUE), 
           filename='output.tif' )
```

Or to multiple files in two steps

```
 rasterfiles   <- list.files("C:\\data", "*.envi", full.names = TRUE)
 d1 <-  overlay(stack(rasterfiles ), 
           fun=function(x) movingFun(x, fun=mean, n=3, na.rm=TRUE))
 d2 <- writeRaster(d1, 'out.tif', bylayer=TRUE)
```