# Writing Multiple GeoTiff File in R

Tags: r, raster, geotiff

I am new R user and read 18 Geotiff file in R and masked the tiff according to my region of interest. I am now unable to write 18 masked Geotiff file.

```
require(raster)
raster_data <- list.files(path=getwd())
s <- stack(raster_data)
spf<-readShapePoly("basin.shp")
rc<-crop(s, extent(spf))
rm<-mask(rc, spf)
rf <- writeRaster(rm, filename=outputFile, overwrite=TRUE)
```

I want 18 Geotiff file masked form my shapefile but the output is only one tif file and It doesn't open. I use search option in the internet but couldn't find appropriate answer to my query.

Thank you

Comment: Could you describe the error you got with your approach?

Comment: You could try to add an extra step with `u <- unstack(rm)` before `rf <- writeRaster(u, filename=outputFile, overwrite=TRUE)`

Comment: or just or just `writeRaster(rm, filename=outputFile, overwrite=TRUE, bylayer = T)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write rasters after stacking them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890369/how-to-write-rasters-after-stacking-them)

Comment: I tried that but the error message appearing there is                                                                                          Error in .local(x, filename, ...) : the number of filenames is > 1 but not equal to the number of layers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll certainly find the answer to your question on SO. It was asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14890369/640783) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25857235/640783) and answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14891318/640783) but also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14907938/640783) with the `bylayer` option provided by `writeRaster`.

try `bylayer = T` if you don't need to unstack them to a list.

something like

```
library(raster)
r1 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
r1[] <- 1:100
s <- stack(r1, r1)
writeRaster(s, '~:/r.tif', bylayer = T)
```

Comment: If you know that it was asked before, you should flag the post as a duplicate.

Comment: The error message is Error in .local(x, filename, ...) : 
  the number of filenames is > 1 but not equal to the number of layers

Comment: @user3356873 - might be simpler to use `writeRaster(s, names(s), bylayer=T, format='GTiff')`.

Comment: @jbaums we'll find several duplicate questions on SO.

Comment: Sure, there are plenty of duplicates, but an effort is made to flag them as such. If you know that the answer is on SO, it's better to flag it rather than to re-answer it.

Comment: @jbaums many re-answers were already provided on SO, but thank you for your comment.

Comment: Sorry for the question @PauloCardoso and thank you for the answer J Baums